# While applying OneHotEncoder - Error: Could not convert Str to float: C148

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Trying to apply OneHotEncoding on the Titanic dataset. The sklearn version is 0.19.2. Labelencoded first and now when trying to Onehot encode, it is throwing up the error 'Could not convert str to float: C148'

First, Labelencoded the 'Sex' and 'Embarked' features, this was done successfully. Now when trying to One hot encode, exception is being raised for the value in 'Cabin' feature which was not meant to be encoded at all. Also, C148 is the value that occurs at almost the end of the dataset.

```
#Label Encoding
encoder= LabelEncoder()
df2['Embarked']=df2['Embarked'].fillna(method='backfill')
array1= df2.values
array1[:,4]=encoder.fit_transform(array1[:,4])
array1[:,11]=encoder.fit_transform(array1[:,11])
df_encoded1= pd.DataFrame(array1)

#One hot encoding
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
hotencoder= OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[4,11])
array1= hotencoder.fit_transform(array1)


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-c14deb702f63> in <module>()
----> 1 array1= hotencoder.transform(array1)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in transform(self, X)
2073         """
2074         return _transform_selected(X, self._transform,
-> 2075                                    self.categorical_features, 
copy=True)
2076 
2077 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in _transform_selected(X, transform, 
selected, copy)
1807     X : array or sparse matrix, shape=(n_samples, n_features_new)
1808     """
-> 1809     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, 
dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
1810 
1811     if isinstance(selected, six.string_types) and selected == "all":

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, 
dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, 
ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
431                                       force_all_finite)
432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, 
copy=copy)
434 
435         if ensure_2d:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'C148'
```

Apart from the solution to above error please also tell me how to update to the latest version of sklearn. I tried updating sklearn using pip install -U scikit-learn, but it installs the 0.19.2 version again.

Comment: `pip install -U sklearn` Scikit-learn update, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the scikit pack you used is old one. Actually you could upgrade it to 0.20.x. Otherwise, you could make it work by method Labelencoder() firstly.